# leakage problem in fluid simulation

Tags: physics, fluid-simulation

I am trying to make water flowing through a pipe simulation.

Below screenshot shows the inflow object(sphere) settings.

[image]

Below screenshot shows the pipe object settings.

[image]

It looks like the water is coming out of another end of the pipe. But the pipe is leaking in the middle.

The procedure that I followed to make pipe is:
Added nurbs path, make it bevel, converted to mesh, added solidify modifier.
.....
I tried with both checking and unchecking the 'is planar' with 0.001 as thickness. In Both cases, the pipe is leaking.

Below screenshots shows the settings of domain.

[image]

[image]

**Please tell me how to solve this leaking problem.**

I am new to blender. Expecting detailed explanation.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Fluid sims and pipes can be quite finnicky, I would suggest making a proxy for the collisions, a second collidor that can be left unrendered that helps patch up any holes. You can also try turning up the time steps or quality of the simulation so it takes greater care not to let it pass through.

Comment: I'd recommend a higher quality bake, as usually that fixes the problem for me.